# Should I put this method in my business object or service or make an extension method

Tags: c#, oop

In my PeriodService I have this method:

```
private IEnumerable<DateTime> GetAllWeekStartingDays(DateTime start, DateTime end, DayOfWeek firstDayOfWeek)
        {
             return Enumerable
                    .Range(0, end.Subtract(start).Days + 1).Select(offset => start.AddDays(offset))
                    .Where(d => d.DayOfWeek == firstDayOfWeek);             
        }
```

the firstDayOfWeek is a parameter from a business object XXX. The above method gets me all days which are probably mondays/sundays within a timespan.

Should I put this method inside my Period Service (where it is atm) as private instance method  or into my business object Period.cs as public static method or make an extension method out of it what I really do not like (hard to track/find them...)

Comment: It depends.  It looks like a utility method that could be useful outside the scope of a single service or a single object.  So in that regard I'd probably end up personally adding it to a static utility class -- perhaps called `DateUtilities`

Comment: Why not put it inside the Period class because each period has a date/day and the GetAllWeekStartingDays will return all starting days of a week and the week holds the periods for every day. For me there is a relation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are a fan of [SRP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle), then you would **not** put this in your Period Service.  This is because it would give the Period Service another reason to change.  For example, if this method had some kind of time zone issue in the future.

If you think an extension method is too hidden, you could refactor it out to a `DateService` class that you can inject into your Period Service.

**UPDATE**:
As per my comment, if the option was open, I would choose to use an extension method for this:

```
public static IEnumerable<DateTime> GetAllWeekStartingDays(this DateTime start, DateTime end, DayOfWeek firstDayOfWeek)
        {
             return Enumerable
                    .Range(0, end.Subtract(start).Days + 1).Select(offset => start.AddDays(offset))
                    .Where(d => d.DayOfWeek == firstDayOfWeek);             
        }
```

Comment: I am a strong follower of fat models and put everything there all static methods. Non-static would be easier to test like a DateService hm...prolly good idea.

Comment: fat models, yes. But clean models as well.  So, you might not want a dependency.  What I usually do is pass an action into the entity that will resolve the dates when the entity needs them.

Comment: However, in this particular case, I would go for the extension method on `DateTime`.

Comment: "...for the extension method..." not for the DaveService anymore like in your suggested solution/answer? What dependency in my model would that be? To the System namespace? I have this anyway due to DateTime properties...

Comment: Yes, the system namespace because you are dealing with `DateTime`, plus whatever namespace you use for the extension.

Comment: I will go for a DateService where my date implementations are. Easy to test/isolate and they are used one time and better to change the DateService when some date stuff changes instead of changing the PeriodService...SRP... ;-)

Answer (score 1):

The `Period` class is not the right place for this method, period :). It's not `Period` behaviour because it does not depend on `Period` state. That's what OO is in a nutshell: combine state and behaviour. `Period` *could* have a method like

```
IEnumerable<DateTime> GetWeekStartingDays(DayOfWeek firstDayOfWeek)
```

and use its own start and end dates (supposed they are there) to return the result.

It may belong to `PeriodService`. A service typically is a class that has some dependencies, like a repository or a web service, and basically serves as wrapper around these dependencies. Methods that do not use these dependencies only make the service too "busy" and usually belong somewhere else, *except private utility methods* that support the service's public methods. So if your method is only used as a private method in `PeriodService` it's where it belongs, because its scope (private) is a small as possible. Otherwise I'd make it an internal (?) static utility method as suggested by Eli Gassert.

Comment: You are right Gert. My Period class has no start and enddate therefore those methods does not belong in this class. And a DateService is rather for reuseability in many places. But these methods are used only one  time and one place atm. So I think yes the current location of the GetWeekStartingDays is best where it is at the moment in the PeriodService. But this has a bad testability as the method is private...

Comment: Private methods can be tested through the public methods they affect. I would not make a method public (or internal with InternalsVisible) just for unit testing. It's all about reducing dependencies.

Comment: What do you say about David`s suggestion making a DateService? This could be easily injected and test and I have one place for my date stuff. This has the most advantages for me.

Comment: Of course you could do that. Esp. when there are more similar methods I can imagine you want everything in one place.

Comment: yes one place therefore I wanted to put it in the period class but those methods do NOT work with the period business object therefore its not the right place. I wish one place + easy testing so I go for a DateService :)

Answer (score 0):

Can we see how you're calling it?

I mean, I got a feeling you already have an `IEnumerable<DateTime>` where you do the call, and every time you make the call, you do repetitive work figuring out the start and end date. In this case, having an extension method of `IEnumerable<DateTime>` could save you from repeating youself.

```
public static IEnumerable<DateTime> GetDays(this IEnumerable dates, DayOfWeek day)
{
     var start = dates.Min();
     var end = dates.Max();
     return Enumerable
            .Range(0, end.Subtract(start).Days + 1).Select(offset => start.AddDays(offset))
            .Where(d => d.DayOfWeek == day);             
}
```

Then you could simply call it like:

```
var mondays = mydates.GetDays(DayOfWeek.Monday);
```

If you still insist having the previous one, you can simply have an override:

```
private IEnumerable<DateTime> GetDays(DateTime start, DateTime end, DayOfWeek day)
{
    return new List<DateTime>(){ start, end }.GetDays(day);
}
```

Notice I renamed your method, since it infers purpose that is narowwer than the capabilities of the method. In other words, you can use the same method to get any weekday within a range than just the starting days of week. This woud prevent other coders from creating a new method to get Wednesdays, for example.

Comment: These datetime methods are called once at one place.